# Unable to download files from the web

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

I am new with Ubuntu (18.04.3 LTS) and have struggled with things since setting up last week, but found my way around. I now have a particular problem I haven't found a solution to online. I'm trying to download files from Gmail, drive, photos or even any website and I just can't. I have tried Firefox and Chrome, but whenever I try to download a file the browser goes a bit dim (as if there is a message like where to save the file, but I can't see it) and nothing happens. Any help would be much appreciated.

Speed from fast.com is 22 Mbps.

```
wget https://sportshub.cbsistatic.com/i/r/2019/09/17/4cb3c303-ce1e-414f-8e86-64302a059e52/thumbnail/1200x675/dc0d3788ab4dd8f8dd2ff78a99d92eba/lionel-messi-barcelona.jpg
--2019-10-27 17:52:23--  https://sportshub.cbsistatic.com/i/r/2019/09/17/4cb3c303-ce1e-414f-8e86-64302a059e52/thumbnail/1200x675/dc0d3788ab4dd8f8dd2ff78a99d92eba/lionel-messi-barcelona.jpg
Resolving sportshub.cbsistatic.com (sportshub.cbsistatic.com)... 2a04:4e42:4::444, 151.101.17.188
Connecting to sportshub.cbsistatic.com (sportshub.cbsistatic.com)|2a04:4e42:4::444|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 136967 (134K) [image/jpeg]
Saving to: ‘lionel-messi-barcelona.jpg’

lionel-messi-barcel 100%[===================>] 133.76K  --.-KB/s    in 0.1s    

2019-10-27 17:52:24 (895 KB/s) - ‘lionel-messi-barcelona.jpg’ saved [136967/136967]
```

Comment: What speed are you getting from your internet connection? Use something like https://fast.com/ to check it and add it to your question.

Comment: Use '''wget''' command to download some file(s). And post results.

Comment: Could you also record screen and post link to it?

Comment: wget works fine. Downloaded image to home. Haven't been able to do the screen recording yet

Answer (score 0):

So turns out ubuntu thought I had a second monitor I hadn't noticed and things were happening there but of course I couldn't see anything. Once I switched it to single display everything was visible. Sorry to take up everyone's time